# Coefficients of Lagrange resolvent

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I'm trying to make sense of some things I read about Galois theory. Let $p$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ with known coefficients $a_i$ and unknown roots $x_i$:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
p(X) &= (X-x_1)(X-x_2)\cdots(X-x_n)  &=& \prod_{k=1}^n(X-x_k)\\
&= a_0 + a_1X + \cdots + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + X^n &=& X^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kX^k
\end{alignat*}

I'm interested in the polynomial

\begin{align*}
r(Y)
&= b_0 + b_1Y + \cdots + b_{n!-1}Y^{n!-1} + Y^{n!}
= Y^{n!}+\sum_{k=0}^{n!-1}b_kY^k
= \prod_{\pi\in S_n}\left(Y-\sum_{k=1}^n x_{\pi(k)}\omega^k\right) \\
&=\bigl(Y-x_1\omega-x_2\omega^2-\cdots-x_{n-1}\omega^n-x_n\bigr)\cdot
\bigl(Y-x_2\omega-x_1\omega^2-\cdots\bigr)\cdots
\end{align*}

where $\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity and $S_n$ is the symmeric group consisting of all permutations of $n$ elements.

I've read this formula in connection with the term “Lagrange resolvent”, but I'm not sure if that's really the correct term since [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_%28Galois_theory%29#Terminology) uses that name only for the inner sum, without the outer product over all permutations. So if you know a better name for this beast, or know in more detail what Lagrange resolvent should refer to, please include that information in your answer or post a comment.

What I'm really trying to figure out, though, is how to express these $b_k$ from the corresponding $a_k$. It is obvious that doing so has to be possible, since the polynomial $r$ is obviously symmetric under $S_n$ and any symmeric polynomial can be expressed as a polynomial of the elementary symmetric functions, which are just the coefficients $a_k$ except for signs. So much for the theory. But how does one do this in practice?

I've worked out the first few examples, and unless I made a mistake, the relation is

- for $n=2$: \begin{align*}b_0&=a_1^2-4a_0\end{align*}
- for $n=3$: \begin{align*}
    b_0 &= a_2^6 - 9a_1a_2^4 + 27a_1^2a_2^2 - 27a_1^3 \\
    b_3 &= 2a_2^3 - 9a_1a_2 + 27a_0
    \end{align*}
- for $n=4$: this is a really long list, I'll paste that below.

All coefficients $b_k$ for $0<k<n!$ which I did not mention explicitely are equal to zero. Apparently coefficients are only non-zero for $k\equiv 0\pmod n$.

So my question is this: **What's the most elegant way to compute these coefficients $b_k$ from the corresponding $a_k$?** Doing so via the full symmetric polynomial in between seems unrealistic for $n\ge 6$ or so. Of course, even the list of all coefficients will become terribly large pretty soon, due to the factorial involved, but I'd hope that for $n\le 7$ there *might* be a more clever way to compute these $b_k$ coefficients from the $a_k$ in a practical way. How?

---

Here is the relation for $n=4$, as promised above:

\begin{align*}
  b_0 &= a_3^{24} - 32a_2a_3^{22} + 464a_2^2a_3^{20} + 16a_1a_3^{21} \\&\phantom=
  - 4032a_2^3a_3^{18} - 416a_1a_2a_3^{19} - 96a_0a_3^{20} + 23392a_2^4a_3^{16} \\&\phantom=
  + 4800a_1a_2^2a_3^{17} + 64a_1^2a_3^{18} + 2560a_0a_2a_3^{18} \\&\phantom=
  - 95488a_2^5a_3^{14} - 32384a_1a_2^3a_3^{15} - 1152a_1^2a_2a_3^{16} \\&\phantom=
  - 30336a_0a_2^2a_3^{16} - 1152a_0a_1a_3^{17} + 281344a_2^6a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  + 141568a_1a_2^4a_3^{13} + 8448a_1^2a_2^2a_3^{14} + 210432a_0a_2^3a_3^{14} \\&\phantom=
  - 128a_1^3a_3^{15} + 23808a_0a_1a_2a_3^{15} + 3456a_0^2a_3^{16} \\&\phantom=
  - 603136a_2^7a_3^{10} - 419328a_1a_2^5a_3^{11} - 31232a_1^2a_2^3a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  - 946688a_0a_2^4a_3^{12} + 3328a_1^3a_2a_3^{13} - 211968a_0a_1a_2^2a_3^{13} \\&\phantom=
  - 2304a_0a_1^2a_3^{14} - 73728a_0^2a_2a_3^{14} + 934144a_2^8a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 852992a_1a_2^6a_3^9 + 52224a_1^2a_2^4a_3^{10} + 2887680a_0a_2^5a_3^{10} \\&\phantom=
  - 31744a_1^3a_2^2a_3^{11} + 1062912a_0a_1a_2^3a_3^{11} - 896a_1^4a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  + 24576a_0a_1^2a_2a_3^{12} + 678912a_0^2a_2^2a_3^{12} + 27648a_0^2a_1a_3^{13} \\&\phantom=
  - 1019904a_2^9a_3^6 - 1177600a_1a_2^7a_3^7 + 18432a_1^2a_2^5a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 6051840a_0a_2^6a_3^8 + 153600a_1^3a_2^3a_3^9 - 3287040a_0a_1a_2^4a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  + 10240a_1^4a_2a_3^{10} - 67584a_0a_1^2a_2^2a_3^{10} \\&\phantom=
  - 3526656a_0^2a_2^3a_3^{10} + 12288a_0a_1^3a_3^{11} \\&\phantom=
  - 423936a_0^2a_1a_2a_3^{11} - 55296a_0^3a_3^{12} + 745472a_2^{10}a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 1056768a_1a_2^8a_3^5 - 249856a_1^2a_2^6a_3^6 + 8609792a_0a_2^7a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 419840a_1^3a_2^4a_3^7 + 6426624a_0a_1a_2^5a_3^7 - 39936a_1^4a_2^2a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 172032a_0a_1^2a_2^3a_3^8 + 11311104a_0^2a_2^4a_3^8 + 1024a_1^5a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  - 180224a_0a_1^3a_2a_3^9 + 2666496a_0^2a_1a_2^2a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  + 884736a_0^3a_2a_3^{10} - 327680a_2^{11}a_3^2 - 557056a_1a_2^9a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 466944a_1^2a_2^7a_3^4 - 7962624a_0a_2^8a_3^4 + 659456a_1^3a_2^5a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  - 7766016a_0a_1a_2^6a_3^5 + 53248a_1^4a_2^3a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  + 1437696a_0a_1^2a_2^4a_3^6 - 22953984a_0^2a_2^5a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 18432a_1^5a_2a_3^7 + 983040a_0a_1^3a_2^2a_3^7 \\&\phantom=
  - 8822784a_0^2a_1a_2^3a_3^7 + 18432a_0a_1^4a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 221184a_0^2a_1^2a_2a_3^8 - 5824512a_0^3a_2^2a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 221184a_0^3a_1a_3^9 + 65536a_2^{12} + 131072a_1a_2^{10}a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 393216a_1^2a_2^8a_3^2 + 4325376a_0a_2^9a_3^2 - 557056a_1^3a_2^6a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 5308416a_0a_1a_2^7a_3^3 + 34816a_1^4a_2^4a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 3440640a_0a_1^2a_2^5a_3^4 + 28803072a_0^2a_2^6a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 86016a_1^5a_2^2a_3^5 - 2555904a_0a_1^3a_2^3a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  + 16220160a_0^2a_1a_2^4a_3^5 + 4096a_1^6a_3^6 - 49152a_0a_1^4a_2a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 2064384a_0^2a_1^2a_2^2a_3^6 + 20217856a_0^3a_2^3a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 221184a_0^2a_1^3a_3^7 + 2211840a_0^3a_1a_2a_3^7 + 331776a_0^4a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 131072a_1^2a_2^9 - 1048576a_0a_2^{10} + 196608a_1^3a_2^7a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 1572864a_0a_1a_2^8a_3 - 147456a_1^4a_2^5a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 3735552a_0a_1^2a_2^6a_3^2 - 20447232a_0^2a_2^7a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 155648a_1^5a_2^3a_3^3 + 3211264a_0a_1^3a_2^4a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  - 15728640a_0^2a_1a_2^5a_3^3 - 8192a_1^6a_2a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 221184a_0a_1^4a_2^2a_3^4 + 7176192a_0^2a_1^2a_2^3a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 39059456a_0^3a_2^4a_3^4 - 73728a_0a_1^5a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  + 1622016a_0^2a_1^3a_2a_3^5 - 8257536a_0^3a_1a_2^2a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  + 442368a_0^3a_1^2a_3^6 - 3538944a_0^4a_2a_3^6 + 98304a_1^4a_2^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 1572864a_0a_1^2a_2^7 + 6291456a_0^2a_2^8 + 98304a_1^5a_2^4a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 1572864a_0a_1^3a_2^5a_3 + 6291456a_0^2a_1a_2^6a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 16384a_1^6a_2^2a_3^2 + 884736a_0a_1^4a_2^3a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 11010048a_0^2a_1^2a_2^4a_3^2 + 39845888a_0^3a_2^5a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 8192a_1^7a_3^3 + 344064a_0a_1^5a_2a_3^3 - 3932160a_0^2a_1^3a_2^2a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 13631488a_0^3a_1a_2^3a_3^3 + 221184a_0^2a_1^4a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 3538944a_0^3a_1^2a_2a_3^4 + 14155776a_0^4a_2^2a_3^4 + 32768a_1^6a_2^3 \\&\phantom=
  - 786432a_0a_1^4a_2^4 + 6291456a_0^2a_1^2a_2^5 - 16777216a_0^3a_2^6 \\&\phantom=
  + 16384a_1^7a_2a_3 - 393216a_0a_1^5a_2^2a_3 + 3145728a_0^2a_1^3a_2^3a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 8388608a_0^3a_1a_2^4a_3 + 49152a_0a_1^6a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 1179648a_0^2a_1^4a_2a_3^2 + 9437184a_0^3a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 25165824a_0^4a_2^3a_3^2 + 4096a_1^8 - 131072a_0a_1^6a_2 \\&\phantom=
  + 1572864a_0^2a_1^4a_2^2 - 8388608a_0^3a_1^2a_2^3 + 16777216a_0^4a_2^4
  \\
  b_4 &= -6a_3^{20} + 160a_2a_3^{18} - 1872a_2^2a_3^{16} - 144a_1a_3^{17} \\&\phantom=
  + 12544a_2^3a_3^{14} + 3456a_1a_2a_3^{15} - 576a_0a_3^{16} - 52608a_2^4a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  - 35584a_1a_2^2a_3^{13} - 1536a_1^2a_3^{14} + 12288a_0a_2a_3^{14} \\&\phantom=
  + 141056a_2^5a_3^{10} + 204672a_1a_2^3a_3^{11} + 30336a_1^2a_2a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  - 113024a_0a_2^2a_3^{12} - 4992a_0a_1a_3^{13} - 233728a_2^6a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 717568a_1a_2^4a_3^9 - 243968a_1^2a_2^2a_3^{10} + 581120a_0a_2^3a_3^{10} \\&\phantom=
  - 14976a_1^3a_3^{11} + 97536a_0a_1a_2a_3^{11} - 16512a_0^2a_3^{12} \\&\phantom=
  + 206848a_2^7a_3^6 + 1567744a_1a_2^5a_3^7 + 1029632a_1^2a_2^3a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 1802240a_0a_2^4a_3^8 + 216832a_1^3a_2a_3^9 - 808960a_0a_1a_2^2a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  + 8448a_0a_1^2a_3^{10} + 264192a_0^2a_2a_3^{10} - 33280a_2^8a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 2082816a_1a_2^6a_3^5 - 2443264a_1^2a_2^4a_3^6 + 3366912a_0a_2^5a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 1202176a_1^3a_2^2a_3^7 + 3584000a_0a_1a_2^3a_3^7 - 81024a_1^4a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 55296a_0a_1^2a_2a_3^8 - 1677312a_0^2a_2^2a_3^8 - 251904a_0^2a_1a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  - 94208a_2^9a_3^2 + 1538048a_1a_2^7a_3^3 + 3217408a_1^2a_2^5a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 3512320a_0a_2^6a_3^4 + 3194880a_1^3a_2^3a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  - 8792064a_0a_1a_2^4a_3^5 + 788480a_1^4a_2a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  - 1400832a_0a_1^2a_2^2a_3^6 + 5378048a_0^2a_2^3a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  + 227328a_0a_1^3a_3^7 + 2635776a_0^2a_1a_2a_3^7 + 387072a_0^3a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 57344a_2^{10} - 483328a_1a_2^8a_3 - 2117632a_1^2a_2^6a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 1613824a_0a_2^7a_3^2 - 4085760a_1^3a_2^4a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 11153408a_0a_1a_2^5a_3^3 - 2699264a_1^4a_2^2a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 6725632a_0a_1^2a_2^3a_3^4 - 9181184a_0^2a_2^4a_3^4 - 139264a_1^5a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  - 1335296a_0a_1^3a_2a_3^5 - 9449472a_0^2a_1a_2^2a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  - 1179648a_0^2a_1^2a_3^6 - 4128768a_0^3a_2a_3^6 + 499712a_1^2a_2^7 \\&\phantom=
  - 65536a_0a_2^8 + 2019328a_1^3a_2^5a_3 - 5668864a_0a_1a_2^6a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 3837952a_1^4a_2^3a_3^2 - 11964416a_0a_1^2a_2^4a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 8028160a_0^2a_2^5a_3^2 + 706560a_1^5a_2a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 1581056a_0a_1^3a_2^2a_3^3 + 13238272a_0^2a_1a_2^3a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 665600a_0a_1^4a_3^4 + 5947392a_0^2a_1^2a_2a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 15351808a_0^3a_2^2a_3^4 + 3489792a_0^3a_1a_3^5 - 1898496a_1^4a_2^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 7110656a_0a_1^2a_2^5 - 2883584a_0^2a_2^6 - 815104a_1^5a_2^2a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 229376a_0a_1^3a_2^3a_3 - 6160384a_0^2a_1a_2^4a_3 - 159744a_1^6a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 1671168a_0a_1^4a_2a_3^2 - 3833856a_0^2a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 23199744a_0^3a_2^3a_3^2 - 2818048a_0^2a_1^3a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  - 18415616a_0^3a_1a_2a_3^3 - 3637248a_0^4a_3^4 + 212992a_1^6a_2 \\&\phantom=
  + 704512a_0a_1^4a_2^2 - 3276800a_0^2a_1^2a_2^3 + 12582912a_0^3a_2^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 638976a_0a_1^5a_3 + 1376256a_0^2a_1^3a_2a_3 + 17301504a_0^3a_1a_2^2a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 9895936a_0^3a_1^2a_3^2 + 19398656a_0^4a_2a_3^2 - 1277952a_0^2a_1^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 1572864a_0^3a_1^2a_2 - 18874368a_0^4a_2^2 - 20971520a_0^4a_1a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 16777216a_0^5
  \\
  b_8 &= 15a_3^{16} - 320a_2a_3^{14} + 2848a_2^2a_3^{12} + 416a_1a_3^{13} \\&\phantom=
  - 13440a_2^3a_3^{10} - 7872a_1a_2a_3^{11} + 1984a_0a_3^{12} + 34880a_2^4a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 59520a_1a_2^2a_3^9 + 5248a_1^2a_3^{10} - 31744a_0a_2a_3^{10} \\&\phantom=
  - 44800a_2^5a_3^6 - 222080a_1a_2^3a_3^7 - 85120a_1^2a_2a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 196480a_0a_2^2a_3^8 + 45440a_0a_1a_3^9 + 16640a_2^6a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 387840a_1a_2^4a_3^5 + 536320a_1^2a_2^2a_3^6 - 581120a_0a_2^3a_3^6 \\&\phantom=
  + 5760a_1^3a_3^7 - 528640a_0a_1a_2a_3^7 - 24960a_0^2a_3^8 \\&\phantom=
  + 3072a_2^7a_3^2 - 165376a_1a_2^5a_3^3 - 1523200a_1^2a_2^3a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 816640a_0a_2^4a_3^4 - 206080a_1^3a_2a_3^5 + 2073600a_0a_1a_2^2a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  + 456960a_0a_1^2a_3^6 + 266240a_0^2a_2a_3^6 + 16640a_2^8 \\&\phantom=
  - 211968a_1a_2^6a_3 + 1571840a_1^2a_2^4a_3^2 - 487424a_0a_2^5a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 1397760a_1^3a_2^2a_3^3 - 2877440a_0a_1a_2^3a_3^3 - 105600a_1^4a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 3420160a_0a_1^2a_2a_3^4 - 947200a_0^2a_2^2a_3^4 - 353280a_0^2a_1a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  + 172032a_1^2a_2^5 + 159744a_0a_2^6 - 2611200a_1^3a_2^3a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 512000a_0a_1a_2^4a_3 + 20480a_1^4a_2a_3^2 + 6563840a_0a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 1064960a_0^2a_2^3a_3^2 + 1628160a_0a_1^3a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  + 2785280a_0^2a_1a_2a_3^3 - 430080a_0^3a_3^4 + 1387520a_1^4a_2^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 655360a_0a_1^2a_2^3 + 286720a_0^2a_2^4 - 271360a_1^5a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 5775360a_0a_1^3a_2a_3 - 5980160a_0^2a_1a_2^2a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 1105920a_0^2a_1^2a_3^2 + 2293760a_0^3a_2a_3^2 + 1085440a_0a_1^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 7208960a_0^2a_1^2a_2 - 1638400a_0^3a_2^2 - 4259840a_0^3a_1a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 4259840a_0^4
  \\
  b_{12} &= -20a_3^{12} + 320a_2a_3^{10} - 1952a_2^2a_3^8 - 544a_1a_3^9 \\&\phantom=
  + 5376a_2^3a_3^6 + 7040a_1a_2a_3^7 - 1536a_0a_3^8 - 5504a_2^4a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 31488a_1a_2^2a_3^5 - 6144a_1^2a_3^6 + 16384a_0a_2a_3^6 - 768a_2^5a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 49792a_1a_2^3a_3^3 + 59264a_1^2a_2a_3^4 - 55424a_0a_2^2a_3^4 \\&\phantom=
  - 30336a_0a_1a_3^5 + 1280a_2^6 - 8448a_1a_2^4a_3 - 136960a_1^2a_2^2a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  + 51712a_0a_2^3a_3^2 - 56192a_1^3a_3^3 + 210688a_0a_1a_2a_3^3 \\&\phantom=
  - 12672a_0^2a_3^4 + 512a_1^2a_2^3 + 31744a_0a_2^4 + 248064a_1^3a_2a_3 \\&\phantom=
  - 397312a_0a_1a_2^2a_3 - 69888a_0a_1^2a_3^2 + 67584a_0^2a_2a_3^2 \\&\phantom=
  - 172928a_1^4 + 391168a_0a_1^2a_2 + 12288a_0^2a_2^2 - 307200a_0^2a_1a_3 \\&\phantom=
  + 409600a_0^3
  \\
  b_{16} &= 15a_3^8 - 160a_2a_3^6 + 528a_2^2a_3^4 + 336a_1a_3^5 \\&\phantom=
  - 448a_2^3a_3^2 - 2208a_1a_2a_3^3 - 96a_0a_3^4 - 160a_2^4 \\&\phantom=
  + 2752a_1a_2^2a_3 + 2368a_1^2a_3^2 + 512a_0a_2a_3^2 - 3328a_1^2a_2 \\&\phantom=
  + 2304a_0a_2^2 - 8960a_0a_1a_3 + 17920a_0^2
  \\
  b_{20} &= -6a_3^4 + 32a_2a_3^2 - 16a_2^2 - 80a_1a_3 + 320a_0
\end{align*}